# Equivalent of row_number for columns dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to apply a function to columns of a tibble, or data.frame, depending on the index of columns. It appears to me several time, and I give just one MWE

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(7,8,9), c = c(3,5,6))
test <- test %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate_all( ~lead(., 2))
```

This will lead by 2 every columns (just an example). But what I want is to lead the first column by 1, the second by 2, and so on. Doing something like `mutate_all(~lead(., col_number())`.

For this little example, I know one way to do it, like:

```
test <- as.matrix(test)
for (i in 1:ncol(test)){ test[,i] <- lead(test[,i], i) }
```

There might be other way to do it too, haven't thought about it much (one needs to convert as a matrix first, otherwise it doesn't produce the right result, I don't really know why).

But I'd like to do it with a `mutate` or `apply`, being able to get the index of column in general. With a more complex example.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `purrr::map2_df` to sequentially `lead` every column based on column number.

```
purrr::map2_df(test, seq_along(test), dplyr::lead)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      a     b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2     9    NA
#2     3    NA    NA
#3    NA    NA    NA
```

---

We can also use base R `Map`

```
test[] <- Map(function(x, y) c(tail(x, -y), rep(NA, y)), test, seq_along(test))
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know about this `seq_along` function

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` `shift`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, Map(shift, .SD, n = 1:3, type = 'lead')]
#    a  b  c
#1:  2  9 NA
#2:  3 NA NA
#3: NA NA NA
```

---

Or using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2_dfr(test, 1:3, ~shift(.x,  type = 'lead'))
```